# Rails Admin controller creating action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, routes, activeadmin

I'm tryng to create a new action to modify a value of a model.

This is my exercize.rb file.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Exercize do

permit_params :consegna, :libro, :spiegazione, :reviewadmin

actions :all

controller do
def approve
   exercize.reviewadmin=1
end
end
action_item only: :show do |exercize|
  link_to('New Post', approve_admin_exercize_path(exercize))
end


end
```

And this is the error generated

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Exercizes#show
Showing /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre4/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `approve_admin_exercize_path' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::ActionItems:0x007fb302ed2fa8>
Extracted source (around line #17):
15
16
17
18
19
20

end
action_item only: :show do |exercize|
  link_to('New Post', approve_admin_exercize_path(exercize))
end
# permit_params do
#   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]

Rails.root: /home/matteo/Scrivania/workspace/schoolexploit

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element.rb:182:in `method_missing'
app/admin/exercize.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:9:in `instance_exec'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in build'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `span'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:8:in `block in build'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:7:in `each'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:7:in `build'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/title_bar.rb:50:in `build_action_items'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/title_bar.rb:24:in `block in build_titlebar_right'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/title_bar.rb:23:in `build_titlebar_right'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/title_bar.rb:10:in `build'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:69:in `build_title_bar'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:48:in `block in build_page'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:47:in `build_page'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:2:in `block in __var_lib_gems_______gems_activeadmin_______pre__app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb___1959187541369977911_70203555889500'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `new'
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4) app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `__var_lib_gems_______gems_activeadmin_______pre__app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb___1959187541369977911_70203555889500'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:16:in `render_with_remotipart'
responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:170:in `to_html'
responders (2.2.0) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:107:in `to_html'
responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in `respond'
responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:in `call'
responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:205:in `respond_with'
/home/matteo/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/inherited_resources-6707bf7e45b9/lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:13:in `show'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
rack-pjax (1.0.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"2"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
x
>>
```

I really tried everything. ActiveAdmin docs are not helping me so much. Please tell me How to solve this.

Comment: did you define routes for `approve_admin_exercize_path` in your routes file?

Comment: @EdmundLee yeah I can't find that, how I can add them?

Comment: rake routes is not helping me.

Comment: Are you using Rails? or are you using those modules individually?

Comment: Yes I'm using Rails

Comment: you should have a `routes.rb` file. You will need to add the route. Follow this doc http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: But the problem is how to create a route for Active admin action. This is the real problem for me

Comment: For example to create the action doing  exercize.reviewadmin=1 what I have to implement in routes.rb and exercize.rb?

Comment: What is `ActiveAdmin`? Is that a model? You are not using rails in a conventional way. Why do you have `controller do` block? I've never used it this way. So I don't know how to help you.

Comment: Is a gem that generates an Admin Backend. However thank you foir tryng helping me :)

Comment: What gem is that? you need to tell us if you are using an external library.

Comment: http://activeadmin.info/

Comment: did you run this? `rails generate active_admin:resource [MyModelName]`

Comment: Sure and this will delete my code

Comment: that's because active admin try to generate the file again. my bad. see my answer. You still need to setup rails. And I highly suggest you learn rails basic before diving into using a gem. Gems can be useful, but it will just confuse you if you don't know rails/ruby.

Comment: Thank you I will solve this in another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveAdmin doesn't setup path for you. You are still responsible for setting up your rails infrastructure.

This https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html is a very detailed reference.

Your error trace says `undefined method`approve_admin_exercize_path'` which is trying to tell you that you don't have the path setup. (Rails use meta programming to construct these path methods for you).

In your `route.rb` file, you should have something similar to this.

```
resources :exercize do
  member do
    post :approve
  end
end
```

**warning**

This snippet above is not exact. I don't know how your app is structured therefore cannot give you the exact code.

Then in your termianl, run `rake routes` will show you all the routes that are available.